# Full-Text Item Count 1 on Table with 8986 records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

using this query

```
SELECT
    FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY(cat.name,'ItemCount') AS [ItemCount],
    FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY(cat.name,'MergeStatus') AS [MergeStatus],
    FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY(cat.name,'PopulateCompletionAge') AS [PopulateCompletionAge],
    FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY(cat.name,'PopulateStatus') AS [PopulateStatus],
    FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY(cat.name,'ImportStatus') AS [ImportStatus]
FROM sys.fulltext_catalogs AS cat
```

i see

```
ItemCount | MergeStatus | PopulateCompletionAge | PopulateStatus | ImportStatus
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1      |     0       |       872792723       |      0         |    NULL
```

ItemCount is 1 on a Table with 8986 records!

If i perform a simple `FREETEXT` query:

```
SELECT * FROM FREETEXTTABLE(Table, Column, 'word')
```

it return only 1 record.

But if i perform a classik `LIKE` query

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE '%word%'
```

it return 332 records.

I have just added for the first time a Full-Text index on a existing table with the auto detect modify and 'Italian' word breaker.

Why my full text index seem to have only one record?